# List (menu) at the top of the page

Tags: html, css

```css
nav[role="sub"] ul li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 5%;
  bottom: 5%;
  right: 5%;
}
```

```html
<nav role="sub">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#test1">test1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#test2">test2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#test3">test3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#test4">test4</a>
    </li>
    <li style="float:right">
      <a href="#test5">test5</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

This is my menu. I want this menu to display at the top of the page, how is this done?

I have tried using this in CSS to move the list to the top of the page but it keeps staying at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. I feel you need to read some basic CSS tutorials before you post any more to SO. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem your css is ok, only remove li from the first:

```
nav[role="sub"] ul li
```

It's making every li element to position absolute, that's why it looks messy.

I added a style for li in case you wanted to show it in a single line.

```css
nav[role="sub"] ul {
position: absolute;
top: 10%;
left: 5%;
bottom: 5%;
right: 5%; 
}

nav[role="sub"] ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<nav role="sub">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#test1">test1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#test2">test2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#test3">test3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#test4">test4</a>
        </li>
        <li style="float:right">
            <a href="#test5">test5</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: This did the same as putting the HTML in a Header tag, I will use this one instead so I have better control of the position, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You can place it in `<header></header>` I guess.